# Route Angular2 application when user changes nav bar manually?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm running the Angular2 sample [tutorial app](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), and when I click links that navigate the application, such as "dashboard" takes me to `localhost:3000/dashboard` and `heroes` takes me to `localhost:3000/heros` without the whole app reloading as expected.

Now if I am at `localhost:3000/dashboard` and I manually modify the URL to `localhost:3000/heros` and hit enter, the app reloads and takes me to the **heros** view, however if I do this with Gmail and other javascript applications the application switches the view without reloading.

What's the name of the components that allow this functionality?

Is there an Angular or Angular2 way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible with the `PathLocationStrategy`.  Gmail, Play Music, and other sites I see this functionality on all have a `#` in their URLs.

I switched the application to the `HashLocationStrategy` and this now functions as such.

The switch is facilitated by the adding an import to main.ts and configuring the router to use it.

`import {Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';`

`bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
]);`